# Need build.gradle with (CucumberJVM4 + Allure) for BDD Cucumber using java

Tags: java, bdd, cucumber-jvm, gradle-plugin, allure

I have a gradle project and I am trying to generate the Allure Reports using CucumberJVM 4. I have referred many blogs and their websites but no luck. Can anyone help me with sample GitHub **Gradle** project with BDD Cucumber using java along with Allure Reports + CucumberJVM ?

I've tried to follow the procedure as per this documentation but '.json' files and my step definitions are not getting executed in the gradle command.

Link: https://docs.qameta.io/allure/#_cucumber_jvm

Command : gradle clean allure **or** gradle clean allureReport

Below are the changes which i have in my build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
    }
    dependencies{
        classpath "io.qameta.allure:allure-gradle:2.8.1"
    }
}

apply plugin: "io.qameta.allure"

allure {
    version = '2.2.1'
    autoconfigure = true
    String allureJavaVersion = '2.0-BETA9'
    aspectjweaver = true
    boolean clean = true
    resultsDir = file('testfolder/build/allure-results')
    reportDir = file('build/reports/allure-report')

    String configuration = 'testCompile'

    useCucumberJVM {
        version = '2.0-BETA12'
    }

    downloadLink = "https://dl.bintray.com/qameta/generic/io/qameta/allure/allure/2.2.1/allure-2.2.1.zip"
}

dependencies{
// Allure Reports
    testCompile "io.qameta.allure:allure-cucumber4-jvm:2.10.0"
    testCompile "io.qameta.allure:allure-cucumber-jvm:2.0-BETA16"
    testCompile ("org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.8.10")
}


import io.qameta.allure.gradle.task.AllureReport

task allureAggregatedReport(type: AllureReport) {
    resultsDirs = subprojects.allure.resultsDir
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go!! - https://github.com/Ragul-Dhandapani/BDD-Cucumber-Allure-Gradle

This project has build.grade (Cucumber JVM4 + Java + Allure + BDD Cucumber). Make sure your cucumber version <5.0. Because Allure Cucumber JVM 4 will not support the higher version of cucumber.

Answer (score 0):

Well, to configure allure 2.0 on cradle you should to do 3 things add `dependencies (also compile group)`, and `allure module`.
And it works.
After that json files will be configured in `result directory`. And you can configure allure report folder by `allure CLI`

See my work configuration

```
dependencies {
    compile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:${selenium}"
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    testCompile 'info.cukes:cucumber-java:1.2.5'
    compile 'info.cukes:cucumber-junit:1.2.5'
    compile "org.testng:testng:${testNG}"
    compile group: 'io.qameta.allure', name: 'allure-attachments', version: '2.0-BETA16'
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "io.qameta.allure:allure-gradle:2.3"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'io.qameta.allure'

allure {
    version = '2.4.1'
    useCucumberJVM {
        version = '2.0-BETA5'
    }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more? It is not recommended to just paste the code with no explanation.